# How to extract a table with Se ans Sp at different cutpoints (ROC) in R?

Tags: r, classification, roc

I am using the cutpointr package in R to create ROC curves and find optimal cutpoints. The objective is to develop a diagnostic test. The diagnostic test value is quantitative and I want to find the optimal cutpoint to classify the tested individual as healthy or sick.

I want to extract a table with the Se and Sp at different cutpoints. How can I do this? I do not find any information in the cutpointr package documentation.

```
cp <- cutpointr(file, assay_value, reference_value, 
                method = maximize_metric, metric = youden, na.rm = TRUE)
cp

plot(cp) # ROC curve
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Do you want an answer with the cutpointr package or do other answers work too?

Comment: I wanted an answer with the cupointr package. As I did not find any solution, I finally used the pROC package.